# I/O contention on RAID disk

Tags: oracle, raid

I found all of the Oracle data files including redo, control, system, index and everything are in just one directory.

That directory is on Raid5 disks.

In this case do I need to do something for optimal performance?

Or in a raid system there is nothing to care about? Since no io contention happens?